# Loud fan: Tried many ways, but can't handle it

Tags: hardware, fan, sensors, fancontrol

hope you can help me, quite frustrating...

I used Windows 7 and had no problems with my fans at all. Using Linux in the university I decided to use it at home, too. When you boot your Computer, your fan starts to get loud, but then gets nearly silent. This does not happen, it keeps being loud. 
I am quite sure the CPU-Fan is my problem. Settings in the Boot-menu did not help in any way; they had no influence on my fan.

**Hardware:**

Intel i5-3570 LGA 1155

MSI Z77A-G43

I have already searched a lot and tried to use fancontrol. But, as you probably know, you need to install lm-sensors first and configure pwmconfig.

**Summary-Output of `sensors-detect`:**

```
Driver `coretemp':   * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Driver `lm78':   * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `National Semiconductor LM78' (confidence: 6)

Driver `f71882fg':   * ISA bus, address 0x295
    Chip `Fintek F71869A Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
----cut here----  Chip drivers  coretemp  f71882fg  lm78
----cut here---- If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are loaded. You may want to run 'service kmod start' to load them.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK Unloading i2c-i801... OK Unloading cpuid... OK
```

**Output of `sensors`:**

```
acpitz-virtual-0 Adapter:  Virtual device  temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit
= +106.0°C)  temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100 Adapter:  PCI adapter  fan1:        4824 RPM temp1:    
+42.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter:  ISA adapter Physical id 0:  +36.0°C  (high
= +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 0:         +28.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 1:         +36.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit =
+105.0°C) Core 2:         +28.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 3:         +32.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0 Adapter:  Virtual device temp1:        +35.0°C
```

Now the reason, why I wrote "but"....
After I installed fancontrol, I did this `sudo pwmconfig`.

**Output `pwmconfig`:**

```
Found the following devices:     hwmon0 is acpitz     hwmon1 is nouveau  hwmon2/device is coretemp     hwmon3 is pkg-temp-0

Found the following PWM controls:    hwmon1/pwm1           current value: 100

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed... Found the following fan sensors:    hwmon1/fan1_input     current speed: 4483 RPM

Warning!!! This program will stop your fans, one at a time, for approximately 5 seconds each!!! This may cause your processor temperature to rise!!! If you do not want to do this hit control-C now!!! Hit return to continue: 

Testing pwm control hwmon1/pwm1 ... /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 226: echo: write error: Operation not permitted Manual control mode not supported, skipping. Testing is complete. Please verify that all fans have returned to their normal speed.

The fancontrol script can automatically respond to temperature changes of your system by changing fanspeeds. Do you want to set up its configuration file now (y)? y What should be the path to your fancontrol config file (/etc/fancontrol)? 

Select fan output to configure, or other action: 1) Change INTERVAL    3) Save and quit 2) Just quit           4) Show configuration select (1-n):
```

The last menu, showing 1), 2),... should show any fan, but, as you see, it does not.

Additional information about that: 
It says "Warning!!! This program will stop your fans, one at a time, for
 approximately 5 seconds each!!!", but the fan didn't stop after pressing "Enter".

Do you have any idea, how I get control of my noisy problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that it is not your GPU fan that is causing all the racket.  I had an EVGA video card that would run at full fan by default, and would only quiet down once the appropriate driver had been loaded.

If it turns out to be your GPU fan, then you will probably have an easier time controlling that than controlling your CPU fan.

Good Luck.